# Storing rarely updated data on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing app that contains many quotations placed in different rubrics. There is also rating system so user can rate quotations. I think that rating data can be stored on device as Core Data.

But what about quotations? Few times in a year quotations list will be updated. How do you recommend to store them?

Comment: Will the question list be updated in diffs or replaced in whole ?

Comment: Yes, it can be updated or even replaced. I am going to use unique id number for each one quotes.

Answer (score 1):

As You need to update your Questions less frequently you should store it to your CoreData and for update you can send a push notification to device and based on that notification device can call the server and update its database, also you can do a frequent check if you not want to setup notification based update.

Comment: Thank you! In this case user need to accept push notifications for my app?

Comment: As you integrate the push user need to allow for only one time and then you can send as many push as you want.